# Getting all rows through peewee based on foreign key

Tags: python, peewee

I currently have two peewee models "User" and "Game". Every Game can have many users and they are related by a ForeignKeyField in User. I'm simply trying fetch all users with a certain game id but I haven't been able to figure out how. So far I've tried:

```
User.select().where(User.game.id == game_id)
```

and:

```
User.select().where(User.game_id == game_id)
```

I'm probably missing something really trivial here so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a *join*:

```
User.select().join(Game).where(Game.id == game_id)
```

The code might differ from what you need, as I do not know how your models look in detail. Please check out the [peewee documentation on joining](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#joining-tables).